# Unusual horizontal lines in a Word document -- not underline, border or Shape. What are they?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Subj. I've got across a Winword document with underlines looking like this:

[image]

- They are not tied to the text typed => it's not font underline
- but are tied to the paragraph: if I add a line break, the line moves:

  [image: tied to the paragraph]
- There are no tables (there are no turtle symbols, nor does the Table ribbon pane appear); paragraph border is not selected, either:

  [image: border not selected]

  (And when I select the border, a *second* line appears:)

  [image: border selected causes a second line]

  => it's not a border
- When hovering, the cursor changes to horizontal adjustment form, so I can't move them around => it's not a Shape

  [image: not a Shape]

**So, what are these strange lines, and how can I edit them or add my own?**

I uploaded a sample document with these lines to https://yadi.sk/i/U1IOapWR3Z7CeZ for the time being so you can examine them yourselves if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are separate paragraphs with `1pt` font and a top border. Lines that don't span the entire page are implemented with a paragraph indent.

This is what it looks like with 500% zoom:

[image: zoomed view with style entry]

A neat trick!

<sub>(The downsides are that you can't have more than one line at the same height and there are bogus input locations in the text (one needs to press Down two times instead of one to get to the next line, and users may inadvertently type text there).

The upsides, apart from the aforementioned independence from text, are the lines are easily created and copied with required parameters, the parameters are controlled precisely, lines are automatically aligned relative to page borders and can be easily aligned to each other and edited together (unlike Shapes)).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Those are borders applied to the text. You can clearly see the borders icon is showing an applied border in your screenshot.

When you add a paragraph break, the border may not appear on the new line, but when you insert a tab, the border will appear.

Comment: I thought I told and showed clearly that when I enable a border, a _second_ line appears. Okay, will tell that even more clearly.